# Getting 'StorageException' even after setting my rules as public. Please see details

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have stored some images on `Firebase` and when I am trying to download them, I'm getting following error: `E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. User does not have permission to access this object. Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403`. I am using Google Authentication too.

Here's how I am uploading image:

```
StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://appname-e2a32.appspot.com").child("hImage");

UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putBytes(data);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        savingHelpRequest.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Here's how I am trying to download it:

```
FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://appname-e2a32.appspot.com").child("hImage");

storageReference.getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        // Use the bytes to display the image
        ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bytes = baoStream.toByteArray();
        bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Here's the security rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
     match /b/appname-e2a32.appspot.com/o {
     match /{allPaths=**} {
     allow read, write;
    }
 }
}
```

Please let me know how can I get rid of this error and download the images successfully?

Comment: Are you using Firebase Authentication or have you changed your default Storage Security Rules to allow unauthenticated access?

Comment: Please see the edited question for Security Rules and yes I am using google authentication.

Comment: are you compiling against 6.0?

Comment: @SohailZahid sorry, I didn't get what you said. If you are asking about `compileSdkVersion` then it is 23.

Comment: @HammadNasir So have you get run-time permission before storing you images ?

Comment: @SohailZahid No. I haven't done anything like that!

Comment: The issue here is that you're trying to download an unnamed object `storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://appname-e2a32.appspot.com");` is the object named `""`. You should instead be using `storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://appname-e2a32.appspot.com/path/to/my/object.ext");` or creating a file name that you can upload/download to or from.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald hey there. please check the edited question. I have done what you said but still I'm getting same error!

Comment: @HammadNasir would you mind filing a bug at https://firebase.google.com/support and sending the bucket name and this SO post so we can debug this in more depth?

Comment: @HammadNasir hey, did you solve this issue? if yes; can you share the solution and its cause?

Answer (score 0):

In Android 6.0 or API 23 we have to get runtime permission from user only declaring permission in manifest is not enough.

```
  public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final int REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = 1;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            checkPremission();
            //SomeTask(); which need permission will become like below in API 23
        }

        void checkPremission() {
            //select which permission you want
            final String permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SampleActivity.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(SampleActivity.this, permission)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SampleActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION);
                }
            } else {
                // you have permission go ahead launch service
                SomeTask();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case REQUEST_RUNTIME_PERMISSION:
                    final int numOfRequest = grantResults.length;
                    final boolean isGranted = numOfRequest == 1
                            && PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults[numOfRequest - 1];
                    if (isGranted) {
                        // you have permission go ahead
                        SomeTask();
                    } else {
                        // you dont have permission show toast
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }


        void SomeTask() {
            FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://appname-e2a32.appspot.com");
            storageReference.getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                    // Use the bytes to display the image
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baoStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bytes = baoStream.toByteArray();
                    bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: why have you called `SomeTask()` twice?

Comment: if you have permission then no need to ask just do you stuff otherwise while you have granted permission ....so thats why twice

Comment: @HammadNasir is your problem fixed?

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Cannot resolve symbol 'WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'`.

Comment: change it to this `android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: I put a `Toast` here and it is being shown, though I was not asked to grant permission:
`if (isGranted) {
                    // you have permission go ahead
                    SomeTask();
                } else {
                    // you dont have permission show toast
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please grant permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114825/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-hammad-nasir).